# С помощью парсинга получил ссылки на картинки

Tags: парсер, изображения, бот

Всем привет, с помощью парсинга , добился того что  "img_url" - собирает все ссылки картинок/артов с сайта, как можно осуществить что б бот рандомно отправлял картинку/арт, рандомно беря отсюда "img_url" ссылку на картинку? Возможно ли это?